# Modifying value char** from C callback in Swift and Avoiding EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, swift, swift4.2

I am working on a project that implements a C library using Swift. So far I have been able to manage how to get String from C strings and some others.

Now I am facing an issue when dealing with a C callback that returns OUT variables type char**. The swift code needs to reallocate memory and change the value. These variables are used for String type.

The Header for the C function is:

```
DllExport void STDCALL DvProviderGetProtocolInfo(THandle aProvider, CallbackGetProtocolInfo aCallback, void* aPtr);
```

And the header for the C Callback is:

```
typedef int32_t (STDCALL *CallbackGetProtocolInfo)(void* aPtr, IDvInvocationC* aInvocation, void* aInvocationPtr, char** aSource, char** aSink);
```

In swift I call the function like that:

```
DvProviderGetProtocolInfo(prvHandleId, { (pointer, aInvocation, aInvocationPtr, aSource, aSink) -> Int32 in

        let senderClass:SenderClass = bridgeToTypeUnretained(ptr: pointer!)

        senderClass.writeCStringValue(from: aSource, withValue: senderClass.sourceProtocolInfoArray)

        senderClass.writeCStringValue(from: aSink, withValue: senderClass.sinkProtocolInfoArray)

        return 0

    }, bridgeToPointerRetained(obj: self))
```

The functions used are:

```
public func writeCStringValue(from pointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?, withValue value:String){

        pointer!.pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity:value.utf8.count)
        strcpy(pointer!.pointee, value)

}
```

And declared in another Swift File:

```
/*** Convert const void* To Any T ***/
func bridgeToTypeRetained<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> T {
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeRetainedValue()
}

func bridgeToTypeUnretained<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafeRawPointer) -> T {
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
}


/*** Convert const void* To Any T ***/
func bridgeToPointerRetained<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(obj).toOpaque())
}

func bridgeToPointerUnretained<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
}
```

So far, for small values, writeCStringValue function works fine but when I try to send a long String like:

```
let aTest = "http-get:*:audio/m4a:*,http-get:*:audio/x-m4a:*,http-get:*:audio/aiff:*,http-get:*:audio/x-aiff:*,http-get:*:audio/mpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=MP3,http-get:*:audio/mp4:*,http-get:*:audio/wav:*,http-get:*:audio/wave:*,http-get:*:audio/x-wav:*,http-get:*:video/mpeg:*,http-get:*:video/mp4:*,http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_TN,http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_SM,http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_MED,http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_LRG,http-get:*:image/png:DLNA.ORG_PN=PNG_TN,http-get:*:image/png:DLNA.ORG_PN=PNG_LRG"
```

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the end of writeCStringValue function.

If I include the code in writeCStringValue function inside the callback, then there is no crash.

Ideally i would like to use writeCStringValue function.

Am i changing the values of char** correctly?

Thank you

Comment: One problem is that your memory allocation does not take the terminating null character into account. Try `pointer?.pointee = strdup(value)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. strdup(value) did the trick. When You say "One problem", do you mean there are more??S :S value vas not nil so i don't understand the terminating null character... You can post an answer i will accept it!

Comment: “One problem” means “the only problem that I noticed so far” :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(pointer!.pointee, value)
```

creates a temporary C string representation of the Swift string `value`,
and copies that to the address given by `pointer!.pointee`.
C strings are delimited by a trailing null character and that is not
taken into account in the allocation

```
pointer!.pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity:value.utf8.count)
```

Therefore `strcpy()` copies one `char` more than is allocated. That may or may
not cause a crash, but is undefined behavior in any case.

`strdup()` does both the allocation and the copy, so a simpler solution is

```
pointer?.pointee = strdup(value)
```

That may be better anyway, if the C function (eventually) releases the string with `free()`.

Comment: Yes it does free(). I have spend a lot of time because my knowledge of C is "ok...". Thank you